# Spring boot is shutting down VM after APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Tags: spring-boot

Is it normal that VM is running after `APPLICATION FAILED TO START`?

I use this to stop it, but I'm not sure if it is correct way :/

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: See what is exactly the Exception e.

Comment: @armagedescu you are right, I will log this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not need to specify `System.exit(1)` in the catch block.

Springboot application will stop if you re-throw the catches exception.

It will close the SpringApplication context and eventually the JVM process will exit.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same. It should exit the JVM process. But it doesn't. There is some code that is run in another thread. I think that is the problem.

Comment: You can open the Jconsole and can check what is causing or preventing the shutdown.